# Rust function syntax question, example seem in nom

Tags: rust, syntax, nom

I'm looking at the `nom` crate for rust, which contains lots of functions to parse bytes/characters.

Many of the functions, such as `tag()`, seen below, process input that's provided not as a parameter to the function, but that appears instead in a second set of parentheses, following what I would call the parameters. If, in examples, one looks for a *needle* in a *haystack*, then the `tag()` function uses a parameter of its own, which is how one specifies the *needle*, but the *haystack* is specified separately, after the parameter parentheses, inside parentheses of its own (perhaps because it's a single value tuple?).

```
use nom::bytes::complete::tag;

fn parser(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  tag("Hello")(s)
}
```

In the example above, `tag()`'s job is to test whether the input `s` starts with `Hello`. You can call `parser`, passing in *"Hello everybody!*, and the `tag()` function does indeed verify that the start of `s` is *Hello*. But how did `(s)` find its way into `tag()`?

Can someone explain this syntax to me, or show where to read about it. It works, and I can use it, but I don't understand what I'm looking at!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of [`tag()`](https://docs.rs/nom/6.1.0/nom/bytes/complete/fn.tag.html) is `impl Fn(Input) -> IResult<Input, Input, Error>`, i.e. the function returns another function. The first set of parentheses is for calling `tag()`; the second set is for calling the function it returns.

This allows you to store the "parser" returned by these functions in a variable and use it multiple times. Or, put differently, instead of the function definition in your question you could also write

```
let parser = tag("Hello");
```

and then call `parser` the same way you would call the function.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I thought the complicated function definition somehow did something to isolate one parameter, such that it would not be passed in in the usual way, but I see now, that the result is a function, and we're just calling that function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`tag("Hello")` just returns a function, which is then immediately invoked with the argument `s`, i.e. `tag("Hello")(s)`. Here's a simple implementation example:

```rust
fn tag<'a>(needle: &'a str) -> impl Fn(&str) -> bool + 'a {
    move |haystack: &str| haystack.starts_with(needle)
}

fn parser(s: &str) -> bool {
    tag("Hello")(s)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", parser("Hello everbody!")); // true
    println!("{}", parser("Bye everybody!")); // false
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2da28f2c586e7811da32b4f4102c09b8)